# Which Petrol bag will fit two SD 702s? 

Tags: gear, bag, petrol, sound-devices

I'm in crazy mode... I have till tomorrow to buy a bunch of gear for a job, so sorry if my question is a bit raw.

I bought myself the [Sound Devices CS-3](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/399052-REG/Sound_Devices_CS_3.html) case, and I'm not a huge fan. I'm about to buy myself a second [Sound Devices 702](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/429566-REG/Sound_Devices_702_702_High_Resolution_2_Channel.html) and was wondering what [Petrol Bag](http://www.petrolbags.com/Sound-Bags) would fit two of those plus accessories (such as a headphone mixer, cables, heaphones, etc.).

Or do you recommend any other bag that can fit all I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you get the back brace optional piece - makes a world of difference when those petrol bags are loaded up.

Comment: @vcprod damn, I just placed my order. I'll try intercept! Thanks. 

Comment: @Andrew Did you bought the small one or the large? Did the small one is large enough to carry two recorders?

Comment: @Davide I got the small one. Fits two 702s fine. It's perfect. 

Comment: @Andrew Thank you. I'll go for the small one too... Placing my order... 

Answer (score 2):

I recently bought the [Petrol PS602 Deca Eargonizer – Large](http://www.petrolbags.com/Sound-Bags?q=node/1170) and it is quite large, heres a photo of it with my 2 recorders & preamp in it:

[image: SD recorder]

It has another largish pocket (holds headphones, camera etc) which is well protected plus another pocket on the front & one on back.... I'm going to write a review & post some photos & video of it this weekend... it is a biggish bag - still carry on baggage size for flying.... its beautifully designed for routing cables & accessing batteries etc....

Comment: Jimminy Crickets, @tim! How are those back pain pills workin' out for you? :-) That thing is a *BEAST*.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing this. Looking at it, I don't actually think I could handle days of running around with this. Although it does look perfect for outings, I'm going to be running around in Mexico with a film crew, and this will without a doubt get very heavy. Did you have a chance to look at the small one too? Would that still fit the two recorders? Should do right? 